# Change price view in option

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I have created a store (opencart) in which i have a product and user can choose the quantity and pack of product. So I have created custom option to choice quantity.

**the price of product is shown like this :**
[image: This is the Image]

I have to add price to to an original price for each pack :

[image]

**now the result Current :**
packs : 
$1.9
100(0)
 
200(+$0.9)
500(+$1.3)
1000(+$2.9)
1200(+$3.9)

**What I want:**

$1.9
100($1.9)
200($2.8)
500($3.3)
.
.
.

You can check link here :
http://www.shopfairpackaging.co.uk/index.php?route=product/product&path=60_69&product_id=52

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more? I can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scriptonomy Your answer is half right it was giving me result of 00 so I did this

```
(<?php
//get first currency symbol 
$symbol = substr($price, 1); 

//get float value form string
$x = floatval(ltrim(ltrim(ltrim($option_value['price'], '£'), '$'), '€'));
$y = floatval(ltrim(ltrim(ltrim($price, '£'), '$'), '€'));
if($option_value['price_prefix'] == "+"){
  echo $symbol;      
  echo  $x + $y;                        
}elseif ($option_value['price_prefix'] == "-") {
  echo $symbol;
  echo  $x - $y;                       
}else{
  echo $symbol;
  echo $option_value['price_prefix'].$option_value['price'];;
}
?>)
```

Tell me if i did something worng

Comment: Yes, if the currency sign is not $, you will get a 0. My solution was simplistic. You could also store the currency symbol in a variable and echo it along with the total.

Comment: @Scriptonomy yes my currency Pound

Answer (score 1):

Opencart options are designed to be cumulative. Meaning that as the shopper selects difference options, the final price gets increased or decreased accordingly.

Opencart does not support the schema that you are seeking. However if you are desperate and need to switch to your own schema, then you could edit the theme files.

To achieve the results you are seeking do the following:

1. Locate the *product.tpl* file in `/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/` folder
2. Locate this line `(<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)` around line number 195, depending on your version
3. replace it with this `(<?php $additive=str_replace('$','',$option_value['price'])+str_replace('$','',$price);echo '$'.number_format($additive, 2);?>)`

Comment: i found it but was giving me result of 00 so I did this